# SOQL Outer Join Multi Level Master Detail Relationship

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, master-detail, outer-join

I am working with a 3 Level Master Detail Object Relationship:

"Level 1" has "Level 2" detail records
"Level 2" has "Level 3" detail records

I am trying to Query "Level 1 records" and using an Outer Join include "Level 3" Records.

e.g.

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Level_2s__r.Level3s__r) FROM Level_1__c
```

Obviously, my notation is not correct. Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to traverse multiple levels in a Parent-to-Child query.

From the documentation

> In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM clause specified Account, the SELECT clause could only specify the Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child object of Contact.

[See Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

You would need to break this into 2 queries in order to traverse to the Grandchild records (Level 3's)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    Level_2__r.Name,
    Level_2__r.Level_1__r.Name
FROM Level_3__c
ORDER BY Level_2__r.Level_1__r.Name, Level_2__r.Name, Name
```

Will mean you'll have duplicate parents & grandparents but well... pay attention when looping through them?

A similar one in case I messed something up:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Owner.Name
FROM Contact
ORDER BY Owner.Name, Account.Name, Name
LIMIT 100
```

You should be careful around subqueries - sometimes they lie and the "related list" will return less records than there really are!

Comment: Yes, I could do that. I am trying to specifically use an Outer Join to take advantage of some functionality in SFDC document merge app Conga Composer. Long story short... The merge tool only allow for 1 level of Grouping in the Output. You can get around this limit adding a second grouping level with an Outer Join. Thanks!